# MS Access Linked Table Issue

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, linked-tables

I have a MS Access database that is run every day. Excel files are downloaded from an online source and are saved as linked tables in my database. Over the past few weeks an issue has arisen with the worksheet names in the excel files. When I run the database I get the following error "OM COMMIT INTL V1$ is not a valid name. Make sure it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long" (OM COMMIT INTL V1$ is the worksheet name in this case). This happens for a number of different files and not just OM COMMIT INTL V1$. Simply deleting my linked table and creating another in the database fixes the problem until I download a new file the following day.  I have been assured that the datasource itself has in no way changed in terms of formatting. The database itself was in no way changed either from when it was running fine. Has anybody experienced this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody who experiences this issue, you must keep the tab name the same when using Linked Tables. As I was combining several files together I needed to have the tab name remain the same i.e. I now name the tab 'OM DOM' and there is no issue.